# Add Date-Time Stamp To Copied File using Windows Batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, time, date

I thought this would be simple but it seems more of a challenge than I thought.

I want a file to be copied and pasted with a time stamp appended. I get the time stamp using this code:

```
set hournum=%time:~0,2%

if %hournum% gtr 9 (set timeback=_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s) else (set timeback=_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s)

Set FileAffected=%1
echo %FileAffected:~0,-1%%timeback%
```

This would make the file, `FILE.TXT` be `FILE.TXT_2015-03-05_11h56m32s`

But I obviously want it to be `FILE_20150305_11h56m32s.TXT`

The file extension could be any extension or any length. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: FileAffected is passed with quotes, so I just stripped them with the ~0,-1.

I did find that if I do this:

```
FOR /f %%i IN (%FileAffected%) DO (
ECHO filename=%%~fi
ECHO fileextension=%%~xi
)
```

If I echo FileAffected I get the full path name with spaces. But if I use the FOR /F command, the filename comes back truncating anything after a space. Even adding extra quotes to the "%FileAffected" variable in the "IN" command, still doesn't fix it, nor does adding quotes around the fi or xi.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I add the date and time as a suffix to a filename?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
set hournum=%time:~0,2%
if %hournum% gtr 9 (set timeback=_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s) else (set timeback=_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s)
echo %~n1%timeback%%~x1
```

Output:

```
F:\test>test file.txt
file_3/01_18h07m40s.txt
```

If your filename contains spaces, for example `file with space.txt` then you need to **call** the batch file with `"`s around the filename, as follows:

```
F:\test>test "file with space.txt"
file with space_3/01_18h07m56s.txt
```

---

#### Parameter Extensions

> `%~n1` Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension C:\utils\MyFile or if only a path is present (with no trailing backslash) - the last folder in that path.
>
> `%~x1` Expand %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt

Source [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Using "Double Quotes

> If a single parameter contains spaces, you can still pass it as one
>   item by surrounding in "quotes" - this works well for long filenames.
>
> If a parameter is used to supply a filename like this:
>
> `MyBatch.cmd "C:\Program Files\My Data File.txt"`
>
> This parameters will be:
>
> %0 = MyBatch
>
> %1 = "C:\Program Files\My Data File.txt"

Source [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.

Comment: Note: `%timeback%` does not include the year for me. I get `_3/01_18h31m52s` on my system, where `%date%` is `15/03/2015`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I will have to trial this later when I get a chance. Weird because I have this same "%timeback%" variable with another batch giving me year. I'll have to look deeper.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I will have to trial this later when I get a chance. I guess your date format is dd/mm/yyyy where in good ol' USA where we do everything backwards it's mm/dd/yyyy. Will have to ponder that one for a bit. http://i.imgur.com/WIKf6TE.jpg