# How to change the number of devices in a endurance test file while scheduling with windows explorer?

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have a bat file that takes 'number of devices' as an argument, runs a performance test and puts the results in a 'results' folder. I am trying to automate running the bat file every hour, which can be done with windows scheduler. The issue is that every time the bat files runs, it just overwrites the results folder. My solve was that I can add a device every time the test runs, but cannot find a way to do that with the scheduler. Does anyone know a technical solve for this or a easier way to implement this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add your batch file contents formatted as code.

Comment: @DavidPostill Done, hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Is your problem to rename the `results` folder on every run? Do you want to keep all of them (new one every hour)?

Comment: yes, so when I run the script, it follows the folder structure environment name > number of devices and puts the results in the last folder with say 10 devices. Next hour it runs, it will rewrite the same 10 folder, I want it to either create a new folder or make the number of devices change every hour. Whichever is easier. I want to keep everyone of the results yes.

Comment: So add the date and/or time to the output folder name. See my answer [Add Date-Time Stamp To Copied File using Windows Batch](https://superuser.com/a/889895/337631)

Comment: Looks like you created a second account. There's a place in the Help section where you can get help with this.